# How do I change/update the parameter actual value to UI parameter value? (after effects sdk, c++)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, adobe, after-effects

How do I change/update the parameter actual value to UI parameter value? (after effects sdk). When I go test the plugin, I change value of **AUDIOSLIDER1** to a number higher than 5. Then, the **AUDIOSLIDER2** actual value changes (inside the code) but not on the user interface.

[RUNTIME **AUDIOSLIDER2** ACTUAL VALUE IS 45](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Ko4o.png)

[RUNTIME USER INTERFACE **AUDIOSLIDER2** VALUE DID **NOT** CHANGE and should be 45](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XK62X.png)

AFTER EFFECT SDK:
https://ae-plugins.docsforadobe.dev/index.html

```
static PF_Err
paramChanged(
    PF_InData* in_data,
    PF_OutData* out_data,
    PF_ParamDef* params[],
    PF_SmartRenderExtra* extra)
{
    PF_Err  err = PF_Err_NONE;

    int test = 100;

    if (params[SKELETON_AUDIOSLIDER1]->u.fs_d.value > 5.0f) {

        //the slider value will be set to 45.2
        params[SKELETON_AUDIOSLIDER2]->u.fs_d.value = 45.2f;

    
        //how to change the slider UI to reflect this change
        

    }


    return err;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the example project "Supervisor":

```
params[SUPER_SLIDER]->u.sd.value = INT2FIX(50);
params[SUPER_SLIDER]->uu.change_flags = PF_ChangeFlag_CHANGED_VALUE;
```

You have to pass a flag that tells AE the UI has been modified